# How can I delete purchased songs from my iPhone4?

Tags: itunes, iphone

How do you remove purchased songs from an iPhone when it is connected to iTunes?

Comment: To clarify: do you want to delete the "Purchased Songs" playlist, or remove specific songs that you've purchased?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use iTunes for this purpose as of iOS 5. It is now ridiculously easy to delete songs. Simply swipe horizontally on any track title and you are presented with an option to delete the song.

Comment: Just be sure to back up your purchases before doing this.